# how to include android library in android studio ????? (Android Studio)

Tags: android

I  installed different packages including (SDK) build tools and updated everything but nothing seems to be working, can any one help ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You need to add the Google Play Services library, specifically the Google Maps com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: You should copy and paste code here instead of a screen shot. Also post the error messages.

Comment: which IDE  you use ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add this in your `app` gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, left most side you can see set of options like Project, Android,Packages, Project files etc.

select Project --> external libraries..add your libraries in it and try